# How do I type + (plus) character on a Swedish Apple Wireless Keyboard using US keyboard layout?

Tags: internationalization, keyboard, character-map

I feel stupid asking this, but my thorough troubleshooting and Google searches rendered no clues…

I'm trying to get to grips with Vim (MacVim) and I've set up Keyboard Maestro to automatically switch to `US Extended` when MacVim activates – conversely switching back to `Swedish Pro` when leaving MacVim.

(Works flawlessly and is very neat since Vim's default shortcuts poses a fair amount of discrimination towards non-english users.)

Dismayingly, however, when using US layout I couldn't find a way to type a simple `+` character… Anyone out there (presumably swedes but others too) who can shed some light on this?

Comment: `+` is Shift+`=` on a US keyboard if that helps...

Comment: hced, please do not feel stupid. We are happy to help with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd> on a Swedish keyboard.

Comment: For me, pressing `Shift`+`´` renders this char: `≠`. (I.e. if I press the key next on the left side of `Del`.)

Comment: It's just very strange... If I open the Keyboard Viewer (Tangentbordsvisning) while having `US Extended` activated, then press `Shift`, the `+` char shows up under the key to the left of `Del` (that you referenced). The strange thing is that it won't be typed if I press `Shift`+`´`, nor will it be even if I click on the `+` with my mouse.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I've isolated the problem (which was caused by a macro in Keyboard Maestro). Closing the question as answered, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a general tip, enable the **Apple Keyboard & Character Viewer** and you can see all the characters that will be produced by the specific model of keyboard that you have, using the specific software keyboard layout that you are using. Hold down the Shift and Option keys, and both at once, and you can see what the results will be.

[image]

[image]

[image: Apple Keyboard Viewer in action]

### Apple Keyboard Viewer in action